# Proving an equivalence relation of a permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Each permutation $σ ∈ S_n$ determines a binary relation on the set $X = {1, 2, . . . , n}$, defined by the condition that for all $i, j ∈ X, i ∼ j$ if and only if $j = σ^k(i)$ for some $k ∈ Z$. Prove that the relation ∼ defined above is an equivalence relation.

So obviously to prove this, I need to show:

Reflexivity: $i ∼ i$ that $i = σ^k(i)$

Symmetry: $i ∼ j \implies j ∼ i$ that $j = σ^k(i) \implies i = σ^k(j)$

Transitivity: $i ∼ j,  j ∼ a \in X \implies i∼ a$ that $j = σ^k(i),a = σ^k(j) \implies a = σ^k(i) $

My issue is, I have no idea how to go about showing these to be true. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Keep in mind that $\sigma^n = e$

Comment: So if we let $k=n$ then $σ^n (i)=e (i) = i $ So then reflexivity is true. But how do I apply that idea to the other two? @morphic

Comment: Now you know that $\sigma^n(i) = i$ so $\sigma^{n - k} (i) = j$. Also if $\sigma^{k_1}(j) = i$ and $\sigma^{k_2}(i) = a$ then $\sigma^{k_1 + k_2} (i) = a$

Comment: Ok. That should be enough to prove the rest of it. Thank you so much. My book didn't say that $σ^n=e$.

Comment: You just have to be aware that this is a group of finite order

Comment: My book is very bad about that. It made no mention that this only applies to finite orders. Thank you for clearing that up. I think I need to purchase an auxiliary text.

Comment: @morphic It is not true that for all $\sigma$, $\sigma^n$ is equal to the identity. Take the example of $S_5$ and for $\sigma$ the product of disjoint $3$ and $2$ cycles.

Comment: @morphic:  The statement $\sigma^n = e$ is neither true (see comment above) nor necessary, because $k$ is allowed to be negative in the definition of $\sim$.

Answer (score 2):

Let me just mention that this can be done quite easily using the fact that a permutation factors into disjoint cycles (directed). The existence of $k$ such that $j=\sigma^k(i)$ is the same as saying $j$ and $i$ are on the same cycle. The relation is reflexive because an element $i$ is situated on a unique cycle, symmetric because $i$ is on the same cycle as $j$ iff $j$ is on the same cycle as $i$ and transitive because if $i$ is on the same cycle as $j$ and $j$ is on the same cycle as $a$ then $i$ is on the same cycle as $a.$